# Error in arraylist

Tags: arrays, object, loops, arraylist, iterator

```
    testSed4 = sedenia4.get(0);

    while (it8.hasNext()) {
        tempRozdiel = it8.next();
        tempSed4 = it7.next();

        if (testSed4.equals(tempSed4)) {
            testSed4 = tempSed4;
            casy.add(tempRozdiel);
        } else {
            casy.add(hodnota);
            testSed4 = tempSed4;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < casy.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(casy.get(j) + " casy");
    }
```

Why I have error in line: tempRozdiel = it8.next();

What is bad in this code ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? If it is a nullpointerexception you forgot to initialize your it8 arraylist object.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
 at appidentifysession.AppIdentifySession.main(AppIdentifySession.java:36)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I can't get here full code because: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." What is bad on it ?

Comment: AppIdentifySession.java:36 is line which contains tempRozdiel = it8.next();

Comment: What type of `tempRozdiel` and Iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (it8.hasNext()) {
    tempRozdiel = it8.next();
    tempSed4 = it7.next();
```

You are only checking if `it8` has a next element, but not for `it7`.

Furthermore, you cannot use `casy.add()` if `it7` or `it8` are iterators on this object.

Answer (score 2):

Exception happens because you are modifying the collection over which it is iterating within the body of the iteration loop.

This is a reason why you got `ConcurrentModificationException` from `iterator.next()`

Comment: @Majkl 1st off we don't know what is going on in your code since you provided as not enough  info. Something changes your list during this action (you posted). About `at8` iterator: post info about this list

Comment: while (it1.hasNext()) {
            ipecka = it1.next();
            agentik = it2.next();
            spolu = ipecka + agentik;
            ipagent.add(spolu);
        }    In this code is it OK, why not in next code?

Comment: I have first list_session which contains 1,2,2,3   .Second list_time contains 30,17,25,46     .When second element of list_session is equals with first element, then add this time to third list_cas else add -1   .The same for third element and fourth etc.